# JAX-RS Web service

Tags: web-services, jax-rs

Can anyone please help me understand the below piece of code? What does the second line doing? I am unable to break down that code. I am learning how to write webservices using JAX-RS and happened to come by this code.

```
String responsedata =
 "{\"custId\":"+list.get(0)+",\"accountId\":"list.get(1)+"}";
return Response.status(201).entity(responsedata).build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `Response` object using [fluent interface](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). `Response.status()` sets the status code and returns a `Response.ResponseBuilder` and sets the response entity body `Response.entity()` and also returns the same builder. Whenever you have a builder, you are using the [Builder pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern). When you're done building the object, you call `build()` which will return the final object. In this case, it returns the `Response` object.